# Android code coverage with Fastlane, Jacoco doesn't support Fastlane

Tags: android, android-studio, code-coverage, fastlane, android-jacoco

I am struggling to get code coverage percentage from Fastlane android, I used **JACOCO** but it doesn't support fastlane. **Xcov** for code coverage is also not having support for Android.

Can anyone suggest any Fastlane plugin or any solution to get code coverage with Fastlane in android project. Thanks in advance!